# Remove characters from text using TRANSLATE function (replace them with empty strings)

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016, sql-server-2017

Let's say I have a string:

```
DECLARE @text VARCHAR(20) = 'abr_akad-ab#ra';
```

and I want to remove all `_-#` characters from the text.

Normally I would user `REPLACE` function to that, something like:

```
SELECT REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(@text, '-', ''), '_', ''),'#','')
```

Can I do that with single `TRANSLATE` statement somehow?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try the following query:

```
DECLARE @text AS VARCHAR(20) = 'abr_akad-ab#ra';
SELECT REPLACE(TRANSLATE(@text, '_-#', '###'), '#', '')
```

it will return the output as `abrakadabra`

Working demo on [**db<>fiddle**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=e4aa907e0c34877110a2cb868881c316)

Comment: Note that, in the example given, you don't need to include the # character in the translate, since it is used as the replacement character for the others, which is later replaced: `replace(translate(@text, '_-', '##'), '#', '')`.

Answer (score 1):

You'll still need use `REPLACE` at some point, as SQL Server requires that the length of parameters 2 and 3 for `TRANSLATE` are the same length. As such an expression like the below will error:

```
TRANSLATE(YourColumn, '-_#','')
```

Therefore what you could do it replace them all with a different character using `TRANSLATE`, and then replace that one character:

```
REPLACE(TRANSLATE(YourColumn, '-_#','|||'),'|','')
```

Comment: I would suggest to use one of the original characters instead of `|`, which should not be touched if present in the source string. E.g. `REPLACE(TRANSLATE(YourColumn, '-_','##'),'#','')`

Comment: Hadn't noticed the extra `(`, must have double hit the key. Thanks @RuudHelderman . Good point of the reuse of the character too.